# langdetect python - to write csv of filename, directory and language

Tags: python, csv

How can I create a loop os.walk() to find all ".txt" files and create an output file .csv with three fields
directory,filename,language ?

I can get the file name & directory by using print but i dont know how to put them in a csv.
Also, i can get the language name using langdetect (`from langdetect import detect`,  `detect("001.txt"`) but i am stuck at looping below issue.

Example

```
Directory  Filename Language
/c/xx      001      en
/c/xx/y    001      fr
```

Code

```
import os
import glob

extension = '.txt'
os.chdir("/Desktop/Language_test")
result = [i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]
print(result)

path=os.getcwd()
extension = '.txt'
for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files_list:
        if os.path.splitext(file_name)[-1] == extension:
            file_name_path = os.path.join(root, file_name)
            print(file_name)
            print(file_name_path)   # This is the full path of
```

the filter file

Comment: ...do you have a question?

Comment: `[i for i in glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))]` ?? just do `glob.glob('*.{}'.format(extension))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this would be good way to do it if you need check for the files in subdirectories as well as the current directory.

It uses `os.walk` to iterate through the directory structure and `fnmatch.fnmatch` to do (simple) filename matching.

```
import csv
from fnmatch import fnmatch
try:
    from langdetect import detect
except ImportError:
    detect = lambda _: '<dunno>'
import os

rootdir = '.'  # current directory
extension = '.txt'
file_pattern = '*' + extension

with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    csvwriter = csv.writer(outfile)

    for dirpath, subdirs, filenames in os.walk(os.path.abspath(rootdir)):
        for filename in filenames:
            if fnmatch(filename, file_pattern):
                lang = detect(os.path.join(dirpath, filename))
                csvwriter.writerow([dirpath, filename, lang])
```

Comment: Its amazing, only part its missing is this os.walk() as i have to drill down into directories too. do i need to loop it like this                                                                        for root, dirs_list, files_list in os.walk(path):
    for file_name in files_list:  with open('output.csv', 'w', newline='') as outfile:
    filedir = os.path.abspath('.')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile)
    for filename in glob.glob('./*' + extension):
        writer.writerow([filedir, os.path.basename(filename), detect(filename)])

Comment: @user3788123: It's hard to read code in comments—so I just updated my answer so it uses `os.walk()` instead of `glob.glob()`.

Comment: @user3788123: Good to hear and you're welcome. My updated answer doesn't use `glob()` anymore, which uses `fnmatch` internally. Instead it just calls the latter function directly. Same difference. `;-)`